Ubuntu 24.04 LTS How to speed up fps for gaming using Google Chrome only 60fps want 165fps?
Which chrome://flags do you change in order to fix this? So google chrome can work fully with a high refresh monitor; like a 165Hz gaming monitor.

The solution:  I figured it out.
1> Enter at address bar: chrome://flags
2> Then SEARCH OZONE
3> Look for PREFERRED OZONE PLATFORM and see if it says DEFAULT.
4> Click on DEFAULT and change this to WAYLAND
With Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Gnome 46 is a Wayland desktop.
When you install google chrome it sets this flag to DEFAULT and that is X11 and uses Xwayland which is slower; better to use Wayland to have a smooth gaming experience.
I hope this helps out others, cause I asked around and nobody seemed to know how to fix this problem.
ps: Firefox that came with Ubuntu 24.04 seems to have this set to Wayland after installation. But I wondered why doesn't Chrome work?

This worked for me - thank you much.
Also disabling the graphics hardware acceleration works, but I prefer your option.
